# Issue: radar graph out of page

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, technical-drawing, tkz-kiviat

I tried to create 3 radar graph in one rows but my graph is out of the page. I guess it is because of ylim set. But I did not find any ways to set a limit on the y-axis. I took this sample code from somewhere on the web. I have changed my data only with the default setting there. My code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-kiviat,pgfplots}


\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=1cm}

\makeatletter
\def\tkz@KiviatGrad[#1](#2){% 
\begingroup
\pgfkeys{/kiviatgrad/.cd,
graduation distance= 0 pt,
prefix ={},
suffix={},
unity=1
 }
 \pgfqkeys{/kiviatgrad}{#1}% 
\let\tikz@label@distance@tmp\tikz@label@distance
\global\let\tikz@label@distance\tkz@kiv@grad
 \foreach \nv in {1,...,\tkz@kiv@lattice}{
 \pgfmathparse{\tkz@kiv@unity*\nv} 
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\result}{\pgfmathresult} % change from \pgfmathtruncatemacro
 \protected@edef\tkz@kiv@gd{\tkz@kiv@prefix\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=1,fixed]{\result}\tkz@kiv@suffix} % used \pgfmathprintnumber instead of "$\result$"
    \path[/kiviatgrad/.cd,#1] (0:0)--(360/\tkz@kiv@radial*#2:\nv*\tkz@kiv@gap) 
       node[label=(360/\tkz@kiv@radial*#2)-90:\tiny\tkz@kiv@gd] {}; % added \tiny
      }
 \let\tikz@label@distance\tikz@label@distance@tmp  
\endgroup
}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[label distance=.1cm,scale=0.37]
% Correlation coefficient
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=a,shift={(0,0)}]
 \tkzKiviatDiagram[radial  style/.style ={-},rotate=90, lattice style/.style ={black!30}]% 
{A,B,C,D,E,F}
\tkzKiviatLine[thick,color=red!20,
                mark=ball,
                ball color=red!20,
                mark size=4pt,
                fill=red!20](0.69967,0.518884,0.666573,0.641628,0.260964,-0.097147)

 \tkzKiviatLine[thick,color=blue!20,mark=ball,
                mark size=4pt,
                mark color=blue!20,
                fill=blue!20,
                opacity=.5](0.69967,0.51442,0.741518,0.683882,0.845317,0.268581)

\tkzKiviatLine[thick,color=blue!20,mark=ball,
                mark size=4pt,
                mark color=yellow!20,
                fill=yellow!20,
                opacity=.5](0.69967,0.516279,0.716755,0.674239,0.84688,0.85819)

\tkzKiviatGrad[unity=0.1](1) % set unity as 0.1
\end{scope}
%PBIAS
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=b,shift={(-17,0)}]
 \tkzKiviatDiagram[radial  style/.style ={-},rotate=90, lattice style/.style ={black!30}]% 
{A,B,C,D,E,F}
\tkzKiviatLine[thick,color=red!20,
                mark=ball,
                ball color=red!20,
                mark size=4pt,
                fill=red!20](0.549194,31.436088,41.019637,48.748227,-34.859838,243.311831)
 \tkzKiviatLine[thick,color=blue!20,mark=ball,
                mark size=4pt,
                mark color=blue!20,
                fill=blue!20,
                opacity=.1](0.549194,31.947443,34.558203,40.005646,-157.190631,-70.267567)

 \tkzKiviatLine[thick,color=blue!20,mark=ball,
                mark size=4pt,
                mark color=yellow!20,
                fill=yellow!20,
                opacity=.5](0.549194,34.251384,36.154543,41.913,-139.627415,-20.655737)

\tkzKiviatGrad[unity=0.5](1) % set unity as 0.1
\end{scope}
% RMSE
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=c,shift={(17,0)}]
 \tkzKiviatDiagram[radial  style/.style ={-},rotate=90, lattice style/.style ={black!30}]% 
{A,B,C,D,E,F}
\tkzKiviatLine[thick,color=red!20,
                mark=ball,
                ball color=red!20,
                mark size=4pt,
                fill=red!20](0.030665,0.0591,0.043113,0.058399,0.022864,0.031734)
 \tkzKiviatLine[thick,color=blue!20,mark=ball,
                mark size=4pt,
                mark color=blue!20,
                fill=blue!20,
                opacity=.5](0.030665,0.059414,0.038696,0.053704,0.023005,0.011813)
 \tkzKiviatLine[thick,color=blue!20,mark=ball,
                mark size=4pt,
                mark color=yellow!20,
                fill=yellow!20,
                opacity=.5](0.030665,0.060144,0.040277,0.055047,0.02086,0.002801)
\tkzKiviatGrad[unity=0.1](1) % set unity as 0.1
\end{scope}


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

And also how to set a title for each graph with a common legend? Any helps will be highly appreciated. Thank you!

I am expecting simillar graph which I have generate from libraoffice with screenshot :([image]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to set a different `step` for each `\tkzKiviatDiagram` I think, that value is what determines the scaling. I chose values so that the plots reach nearly to the edge, you might want to adjust that.

`tkz-kiviat` is only made for positive values I think, so some modifications of `\tkz@KiviatLine` are needed to get reasonable results for negative values. While the code below appears to work, it is perhaps not that convenient to use. I've added some comments to describe where things have changed from the definition of `\tkz@KiviatLine` in the package code.

Note I made a couple of changes in your redefinition of `\tkz@KiviatGrad`, to get the axis labels placed better, and to be able to set the precision for the labels. I also start the loop at `0` instead of `1`, so you get a label for the center point.

To make the diagrams a bit more tidy, I set `lattice=5,gap=1`. Note that `lattice`, `gap` and `step` are all linked, so when the `gap` is doubled (default is `0.5`), the `step` must be halved.

To get a title for each graph you can make use of the fact that you've named the `local bounding box`es, so you can place a `\node` relative to those, as seen in the code below.

I also show one method of making a legend. To make this a lot easier, I defined three styles for the three plots, which reduces code repetition, and makes changing the look a lot more convenient.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-kiviat,pgfplots}
\makeatletter
\def\tkz@KiviatGrad[#1](#2){% 
\begingroup
\pgfkeys{/kiviatgrad/.cd,
graduation distance= 0 pt,
prefix ={},
suffix={},
unity=1,
% added the following four lines
label precision/.store in=\gradlabel@precision,
label precision=1,
zero point/.store in=\tkz@grad@zero,
zero point=0
}
\pgfqkeys{/kiviatgrad}{#1}% 
\let\tikz@label@distance@tmp\tikz@label@distance
\global\let\tikz@label@distance\tkz@kiv@grad
  % started loop at zero, to get label for center point
 \foreach \nv in {0,...,\tkz@kiv@lattice}{
 % skipped the \pgfmathparse, moved
 % \tkz@kiv@unity*\nv-\tkz@grad@zero
 % into \pgfmathsetmacro. The last term is added
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\result}{\tkz@kiv@unity*\nv-\tkz@grad@zero} % change from \pgfmathtruncatemacro
 % NOTE: use \gradlabel@precision for the precision
 \protected@edef\tkz@kiv@gd{%
    \tkz@kiv@prefix%
    \pgfmathprintnumber[precision=\gradlabel@precision,fixed]{\result}%% used \pgfmathprintnumber instead of "$\result$"
    \tkz@kiv@suffix} 
    \path[/kiviatgrad/.cd,#1] (0:0)--(360/\tkz@kiv@radial*#2:\nv*\tkz@kiv@gap)
       % NOTE: (360/\tkz@kiv@radial*#2)-90  -> (360/\tkz@kiv@radial*#2)
       % removed 90 because you rotate all the diagrams
       node[label=(360/\tkz@kiv@radial*#2):\tiny\tkz@kiv@gd] {}; % added \tiny
      }
 \let\tikz@label@distance\tikz@label@distance@tmp  
\endgroup
}%


\def\tkz@KiviatLine[#1](#2,#3){% 
\begingroup
\pgfkeys{/kiviatline/.cd,
fill= {},
opacity=.5,
% add these two lines, similar to for kiviatline
zero point/.store in=\tkz@line@zero,
zero point=0
}
%
% the code below has a lot of polar coordinates, of the form
%   (angle: <value> * <some factor>)
% all have been modified to get them on the form
%   (angle:{(<value>+\tkz@line@zero) * <some factor>})
% note extra braces, which are required when a component contains ()
% 
\pgfqkeys{/kiviatline}{#1}%   opacity ??????
\ifx\tkzutil@empty\tkz@kivl@fill \else 
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
 \path[fill=\tkz@kivl@fill,opacity=\tkz@kivl@opacity] (360/\tkz@kiv@radial*0:{(#2+\tkz@line@zero)*\tkz@kiv@gap*\tkz@kiv@step})   
\foreach \v [count=\rang from 1] in {#3}{%  
 -- (360/\tkz@kiv@radial*\rang:{(\v+\tkz@line@zero)*\tkz@kiv@gap*\tkz@kiv@step}) } -- (360/\tkz@kiv@radial*0:{(#2+\tkz@line@zero)*\tkz@kiv@gap*\tkz@kiv@step}); 
 \end{scope}
 \fi       
% added overlay option because something weird happened with the bounding box
\draw[#1,opacity=1,overlay] (0:{(#2+\tkz@line@zero)*\tkz@kiv@gap}) plot coordinates {(360/\tkz@kiv@radial*0:{(#2+\tkz@line@zero)*\tkz@kiv@gap*\tkz@kiv@step})}  
\foreach \v [count=\rang from 1] in {#3}{%  
 -- (360/\tkz@kiv@radial*\rang:{(\v+\tkz@line@zero)*\tkz@kiv@gap*\tkz@kiv@step}) plot coordinates {(360/\tkz@kiv@radial*\rang:{(\v+\tkz@line@zero)*\tkz@kiv@gap*\tkz@kiv@step})}} -- (360/\tkz@kiv@radial*0:{(#2+\tkz@line@zero)*\tkz@kiv@gap*\tkz@kiv@step});   
\endgroup
}%  

\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  label distance=.1cm,
  scale=0.37,
  plot1/.style={
    thick,
    draw=red!40,
    fill=red!20,
    mark=ball,
    mark options={
     ball color=red, % note ball color inside mark options
     mark size=4pt
    }
  },
  plot2/.style={
    thick,
    draw=blue!40,
    fill=blue!40,
    mark=ball,
    mark options={
      mark size=4pt,
      ball color=blue
    },
    opacity=.5
  },
  plot3/.style={
    thick,
    draw=blue!20,
    fill=yellow!20,
    mark=ball,
    mark options={
      mark size=4pt,
      ball color=yellow
    },
    opacity=.5
  }
]

% Correlation coefficient
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=a,shift={(0,0)}]

% define some macros for convenience
\newcommand\KivStep{4}
\pgfmathsetmacro\Unity{1/\KivStep}
\newcommand\zeroshift{0.2}

 \tkzKiviatDiagram[
   radial  style/.style ={-},
   rotate=90, 
   lattice style/.style ={black!30},
   step=\KivStep,
   gap=1,
   lattice=5
]% 
{A,B,C,D,E,F}

% I don't really know why /kiviatline/ is necessary here
% but it is, unfortunately
\tkzKiviatLine[
  /kiviatline/zero point=\zeroshift,
  plot1
](0.69967,0.518884,0.666573,0.641628,0.260964,-0.097147)
\tkzKiviatLine[
  /kiviatline/zero point=\zeroshift,
  plot2
](0.69967,0.51442,0.741518,0.683882,0.845317,0.268581)
\tkzKiviatLine[
  /kiviatline/zero point=\zeroshift,
  plot3
](0.69967,0.516279,0.716755,0.674239,0.84688,0.85819)

\tkzKiviatGrad[unity=\Unity, label precision=2, zero point=\zeroshift](0) % set unity as 0.1
\end{scope}
%PBIAS
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=b,shift={(-15,0)}]

\newcommand\KivStep{0.01}
\pgfmathsetmacro\Unity{1/\KivStep}
\newcommand\zeroshift{200}

 \tkzKiviatDiagram[
   radial  style/.style ={-},
   rotate=90,
   lattice style/.style ={black!30},
   step=\KivStep,
   gap=1,
   lattice=5
]% 
{A,B,C,D,E,F}


\tkzKiviatLine[
  /kiviatline/zero point=\zeroshift,
  plot1
](0.549194,31.436088,41.019637,48.748227,-34.859838,243.311831)
\tkzKiviatLine[
  /kiviatline/zero point=\zeroshift,
  plot2
](0.549194,31.947443,34.558203,40.005646,-157.190631,-70.267567)
\tkzKiviatLine[
  /kiviatline/zero point=\zeroshift,
  plot3
](0.549194,34.251384,36.154543,41.913,-139.627415,-20.655737)

\tkzKiviatGrad[unity=\Unity, zero point=\zeroshift](0) % set unity as 0.1
\end{scope}
% RMSE
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=c,shift={(15,0)}]
\newcommand\KivStep{75}
\pgfmathsetmacro\Unity{1/\KivStep}

\tkzKiviatDiagram[
  radial  style/.style ={-},
  rotate=90,
  lattice style/.style ={black!30},
  step=\KivStep,
  gap=1,
  lattice=5
]% 
{A,B,C,D,E,F}

\tkzKiviatLine[plot1](0.030665,0.0591,0.043113,0.058399,0.022864,0.031734)
\tkzKiviatLine[plot2](0.030665,0.059414,0.038696,0.053704,0.023005,0.011813)
\tkzKiviatLine[plot3](0.030665,0.060144,0.040277,0.055047,0.02086,0.002801)

% need more decimals for labels
\tkzKiviatGrad[unity=\Unity, label precision=3](0)
\end{scope}


\node [above] at (a.north) {Foo};
\node [above] at (b.north) {Bar};
\node [above] at (c.north) {Baz};

\matrix [above] at (current bounding box.north) {
  \filldraw [plot1,scale=0.5] plot coordinates {(0,0)(1,0)(1,0.5)(0,0.5)} -- cycle; & \node[anchor=base]{Lorem}; &
  \filldraw [plot2,scale=0.5] plot coordinates {(0,0)(1,0)(1,0.5)(0,0.5)} -- cycle; & \node[anchor=base]{ipsum}; &
  \filldraw [plot3,scale=0.5] plot coordinates {(0,0)(1,0)(1,0.5)(0,0.5)} -- cycle; & \node[anchor=base]{dolor}; \\
};


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Didn't fix that, but I think to get correct values for the axis, you want `unity = 1/step`. So for the first one with `step=10`, you want `unity=0.1`, for the second `step=0.04` gives `unity=25`, and finally `step=150` gives `unity=0.00666`.

Comment: Thank you Torbjørn. I will to fix axis value as you suggested

Comment: Wowww. It is excellent. +1

Comment: @bikuser I just edited (https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/419948/revisions).

Comment: @Torbjørn T, Sorry for writing you again. Now I realize that the values in plot A are in Negative but the scale doesn't showed that. That's why it's different then I was expecting. Could you please help me to fix that?

Comment: @bikuser Well, I guess the package was written with only positive values in mind, so negative values will simply end up on the wrong axis. Hence, one needs to reimplement parts of the package. Will have a look at it sometime today, but wont promise anything right now.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thank you for writing. I will be waiting for your further suggestions. Thank you very much.

Comment: @bikuser OK, that wasn't actually that hard. Don't think I screwed up, but let me know if anything looks extremely wrong.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Wow now its exactly the same that I created from libraoffice calc. Thank you so much..you saved my life :)